# How to change the way representing polygons

Tags: polygons

```
Polygon[{{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 
269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}, {{572.752, 
292.812}, {705.658, 191.098}, {624., 334.}, {609.854, 
348.146}, {570.475, 297.83}}, {{464.802, 381.573}, {498.744, 
331.34}, {508.086, 332.982}, {505.5, 348.5}, {495.722, 
397.392}, {479.103, 393.349}}, {{445.321, 368.088}, {442.997, 
358.128}, {485.639, 320.816}, {498.744, 331.34}, {464.802, 
381.573}, {458.299, 382.565}}, {{570.475, 297.83}, {609.854, 
348.146}, {624., 375.429}, {625.503, 378.65}, {565.059, 
397.838}, {543.815, 331.653}}, {{776., 105.25}, {776., 134.549}, {705.658, 
191.098}, {572.752, 292.812}, {481.892, 231.621}, {493.478, 
206.559}, {568.92, 105.25}}}]
```

I want to change the representing way into the following

```
{Polygon[{{609.854, 348.146}, {624., 334.}, {624., 375.429}}], 
Polygon[{{181.75, 333.5}, {174.732, 335.659}, {169.333, 308.667}}], 
Polygon[{{505.5, 348.5}, {505.5, 402.7}, {495.722, 397.392}}], 
Polygon[{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 
269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}], 
Polygon[{{164.187, 285.679}, {151.82, 301.851}, {115.851, 
310.269}, {159.994, 247.949}}], 
Polygon[{{568.92, 105.25}, {493.478, 206.559}, {450.574, 
182.043}, {416.444, 105.25}}], 
Polygon[{{211.75, 105.25}, {192.852, 199.739}, {127.386, 
195.063}, {10.308, 105.25}}], 
Polygon[{{371.196, 478.75}, {401.311, 381.457}, {443.24, 
399.906}, {430.367, 478.75}}], 
Polygon[{{543.815, 331.653}, {565.059, 397.838}, {550.145, 
438.549}, {510.5, 405.7}, {510.5, 333.086}}], 
Polygon[{{173.74, 242.534}, {177.482, 278.082}, {164.187, 
285.679}, {159.994, 247.949}, {164.211, 239.253}}], 
Polygon[{{401.402, 242.039}, {417.449, 261.095}, {341.933, 
321.272}, {332.108, 319.133}, {338.605, 267.158}}], 
Polygon[{{416.444, 105.25}, {450.574, 182.043}, {339.913, 
162.514}, {317.763, 138.438}, {315.55, 105.25}}], 
Polygon[{{415.662, 339.5}, {403.897, 370.269}, {399.794, 
374.757}, {356.729, 357.139}, {351.171, 339.5}}], 
Polygon[{{76.8045, 284.438}, {106.84, 315.197}, {108.887, 
328.131}, {92.7084, 370.825}, {32.397, 334.638}}], 
Polygon[{{209.734, 327.281}, {181.75, 333.5}, {169.333, 
308.667}, {168.212, 304.743}, {178.794, 304.413}}], 
Polygon[{{505.5, 348.5}, {508.086, 332.982}, {510.5, 
333.086}, {510.5, 405.7}, {505.5, 402.7}}]}
```

Is there anyone can answer the question?

Comment: Can you explain the connection between both "representations"?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Dr.belisarius  Hi if there is no connection, i just simply want to change the representing way? Like Polygon[{{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 
269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}, {{572.752, 
292.812}, {705.658, 191.098}, {624., 334.}, {609.854, 
348.146}, {570.475, 297.83}}}]   to  Polygon[{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 
269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}], 
Polygon[{{572.752, 
292.812}, {705.658, 191.098}, {624., 334.}, {609.854, 
348.146}, {570.475, 297.83}}]

Comment: You can use `Thread`.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks for your prompt reply, is that possible to paste the code for me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
poly = Polygon[{{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 
      269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}, {{572.752, 292.812}, {705.658, 
      191.098}, {624., 334.}, {609.854, 348.146}, {570.475, 
      297.83}}, {{464.802, 381.573}, {498.744, 331.34}, {508.086, 
      332.982}, {505.5, 348.5}, {495.722, 397.392}, {479.103, 
      393.349}}, {{445.321, 368.088}, {442.997, 358.128}, {485.639, 
      320.816}, {498.744, 331.34}, {464.802, 381.573}, {458.299, 
      382.565}}, {{570.475, 297.83}, {609.854, 348.146}, {624., 
      375.429}, {625.503, 378.65}, {565.059, 397.838}, {543.815, 
      331.653}}, {{776., 105.25}, {776., 134.549}, {705.658, 
      191.098}, {572.752, 292.812}, {481.892, 231.621}, {493.478, 
      206.559}, {568.92, 105.25}}}];
```

You have not explained how, in general, to subdivide the original `Polygon` to get the shown representaion. Using instead the original list structure.

```
polys = Polygon /@ poly[[1]];

colors = ColorData[10] /@ Range[Length[polys]];

Graphics[Transpose[{colors, polys}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another way is with `Thread`:

```
Thread[Polygon[{{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 
 269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}, {{572.752, 292.812}, {705.658, 
 191.098}, {624., 334.}, {609.854, 348.146}, {570.475, 
 297.83}}, {{464.802, 381.573}, {498.744, 331.34}, {508.086, 
 332.982}, {505.5, 348.5}, {495.722, 397.392}, {479.103, 
 393.349}}, {{445.321, 368.088}, {442.997, 358.128}, {485.639, 
 320.816}, {498.744, 331.34}, {464.802, 381.573}, {458.299, 
 382.565}}, {{570.475, 297.83}, {609.854, 348.146}, {624., 
 375.429}, {625.503, 378.65}, {565.059, 397.838}, {543.815, 
 331.653}}, {{776., 105.25}, {776., 134.549}, {705.658, 
 191.098}, {572.752, 292.812}, {481.892, 231.621}, {493.478, 
 206.559}, {568.92, 105.25}}}]]
```

> ```
> {
>  Polygon[{{442.997, 358.128}, {424., 329.}, {436.438, 269.919}, {485.639, 320.816}}], 
>  Polygon[{{572.752, 292.812}, {705.658, 191.098}, {624., 334.}, {609.854, 348.146}, {570.475, 297.83}}], 
>  Polygon[{{464.802, 381.573}, {498.744, 331.34}, {508.086, 332.982}, {505.5, 348.5}, {495.722, 397.392}, {479.103, 393.349}}], 
>  Polygon[{{445.321, 368.088}, {442.997, 358.128}, {485.639, 320.816}, {498.744, 331.34}, {464.802, 381.573}, {458.299, 382.565}}], 
>  Polygon[{{570.475, 297.83}, {609.854, 348.146}, {624., 375.429}, {625.503, 378.65}, {565.059, 397.838}, {543.815, 331.653}}], 
>  Polygon[{{776., 105.25}, {776., 134.549}, {705.658, 191.098}, {572.752, 292.812}, {481.892, 231.621}, {493.478, 206.559}, {568.92, 105.25}}]
> }
> ```